# Refreshing a page with javascript using php header('location')

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers, refresh

I want use a single php file to handle all of my voting requests.

Currently the script will, if `siteType` isn't set, forward the user and display a message. If the user has `JS` on then it will return a json object and ajax the page.

```
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['siteType'])){
            displayMessages('bad', 'Before you can continue you must select which category you would like to be in.');
            header('Location:/');
            exit;
        }
```

I need it as that if this php code above is executed the page will reload, i assume with javascript and reading the http headers?

**[Edit]** 
I didn't make myself clear enough, but this is a ajax request. I don't output any html. So this really is just about getting js to handle the header?

Comment: Your not allowed to use header() AFTER outputting data to the HTTP stream.

Comment: so... JavaScript  will do this already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *Refreshing a page with javascript using php header('location')*
Because, header('Location: xxx'); must be the only output of your PHP script, it is a header, you can not put it after javascript syntax

Comment: but i want my `js` to handle the header... why would but the header before the javascript syntax? Maybe i didn't make myself clear

Comment: while this wasn't a solution to my problem it still gives good information on the issue for others.

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
```

Javascript

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: its a ajax json request. I won't this to work as i can't output any html

Comment: cheer fella. Boy i don't think i made the question clear enough.
So the javascript won't know when to reload the page.

Comment: The javascript will know when to reload the page, if you put that javascript code inside braces `{ }`.

Comment: I am sure. `if(!isset($_COOKIE['siteType'])){      window.location.reload();      }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be some solution for you,

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['siteType'])){
     displayMessages('bad', 'Before you can continue you must select which category you would like to be in.');
     echo '<script>window.location.reload()</script>';
     exit;
 }
```

Comment: I'd go with a `meta` refresh tag instead of a script in case JS is disabled.